# How to center the text vertically and horizontally without losing the inline-block property?

Tags: css, vertical-text, horizontal-line

I am just learning CSS and would like to ask for help. I can center the text vertically and horizontally but at the expense of the inline-block property. So my question is: how to center the text vertically and horizontally without losing the inline-block property in the .aboutme-trio__section element ?

`https://codepen.io/WitekItDev/pen/bGKgemp`

I am just starting out, please bear with me.

I have tried these methods:
`https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html`

The result? Everything comes crashing down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: could you please provide your desire output?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

To center the content inside your `.aboutme-introduction__section` element you can add the following:

```
.aboutme-introduction__section {
    // your other styles for the section plus:
    display: flex;
    flex-direction-column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

- The `display: flex` make the element a flex container, which allows you to easily center the elements inside it
- the `flex-direction: column` tell the element to stack the elements vertically instead of placing then horizontally side-by-side
- `align-items: center` centers the children items on the cross-axis
- `justify-content: center` center the children items on the main-axis

Then you get:

```css
.aboutme-introduction__background {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.aboutme-introduction__section {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(173, 169, 206);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutme-introduction">
  <div class="aboutme-introduction__background">
    <div class="aboutme-introduction__section">
      <div class="aboutme-introduction__photo"></div>
      <div class="aboutme-introduction__title">O MNIE</div>
      <div class="aboutme-introduction__description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et illum rerum aliquid corporis, obcaecati ipsam doloribus harum labore nisi ad temporibus dolorem voluptate esse maxime illo eius. Nobis, minima laudantium.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is some good information about it on MDN:

- [How to align items on a flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)
- [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)
- [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)